# Identifying type of QspatiaLite field?

Tags: qgis, qspatialite

I am using QspatiaLite in QGIS 2.14. 
I am having problem updating a column of my table and I suspect that the types (integer, real, text etc.) are not consistent.

How can I know which are the types of the fields of my table imported from QGIS into QspatiaLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the CREATE TABLE statement with SQL. Spatialite-gui has a special menu tool for that : right-click the table name and choose 'Show columns'

But you can get the answer with ogrinfo as well:

```
ogrinfo my_spatialite_db.sqlite -sql "SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'my_table'"
```